# Please help me with this query

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables in MySQL:

```
emp_detail
----------------------------------------------------------------------
emp_number(int)| emp_id(int) | emp_name(varchar) | joined_date (date)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
emp_termination
----------------------------------------------------------------------
emp_number(int)foreign key| termination_reason(varchar) | termination_date (date)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want monthly records for year with count of employees who left or joined the company in every month like this :

```
-----------------------
month | joined | left 
-----------------------
```

Comment: Can you add sample data please?

Comment: Do everyone a favor, that includes yourself and please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title thanks!

Comment: yes jeans like int values will be like 1,2,3..., varchar will be simple string  dates are in format '01-02-2014' i want count of employees who joined and left(terminated) in months in year  tell me if you need further more info and thanks for replying

Comment: @sawpnil1988: kindly post a sqlfiddle if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to get joined and left employees in two rows and then combine by month to get left and joined in a single row.

```
SELECT year, month, SUM(joined), SUM(left)
FROM
    (SELECT YEAR(ed.joined_date) AS year, MONTH(ed.joined_date) AS month, COUNT(MONTH(ed.joined_date)) AS joined, 0 AS left
    FROM emp_detail AS ed
    GROUP BY YEAR(ed.joined_date), MONTH(ed.joined_date) 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YEAR(ed.termination_date) AS year, MONTH(ed.termination_date) AS month, COUNT(MONTH(et.termination_date)) AS left, 0 AS joined
    FROM emp_termination AS et
    GROUP BY YEAR(ed.termination_date), MONTH(et.termination_date)) AS my_table
GROUP BY year, month
```

Comment: may be you need to use year as well in the group by

Comment: Yeah if we add year then it will start considering the data for every year, right now 2010 and 2011 would be counted in same year. Cool i will add year too

Comment: @Swapnil1988: Please use the new query now.

Comment: that works but not completely ....i have one termination in 4th month but it shows it in 5th month count

Comment: @Swapnil1988: Please run the new query, it won't be an issue now.

Comment: I have come across this but this doesnt select month in which only termination occures and not joining                   SELECT MONTHNAME(e.joined_date) as j_month_name,COUNT(e.employee_id) as count_join,
(SELECT COUNT(et.emp_number) FROM emp_termination as et WHERE YEAR(et.termination_date)=YEAR(CURDATE()) and MONTH(et.termination_date)=MONTH(e.joined_date)) as count_left
FROM hs_hr_employee as e  left join ohrm_emp_termination as et2 on e.emp_number=et2.emp_number WHERE YEAR(joined_date)=YEAR(CURDATE()) or YEAR(et2.termination_date)=YEAR(CURDATE()) GROUP BY MONTH(e.joined_date);

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select table1.monthname, table1.Joined, table2.LeftCop from 
(
select  year(joined_date) year 
        , MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE( month(joined_date) , '%m')) as monthname
        ,count(*) as Joined 
        ,0 as LeftCop 
        from emp_detail
  group by  month(joined_date) , year(joined_date) 

) Table1

join 

(
select  year(termination_date) year 
        , MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE( month(termination_date) , '%m')) as monthname
        ,0 as Joined 
        ,count(*) as LeftCop  
        from emp_termination
  group by  month(termination_date) , year(termination_date) 
) table2 

on table1.year = table2.year and table1.monthname = table2.monthname
```